# Wordpress add rewrite rules and conditions in plugin development

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to add the following extra rules and conditions to wordpress htacess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

So in my plugin code i have added

```
function write_authorization_conditions(){
  global $wp_rewrite;

  $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("RewriteCond","%{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)",null); //this fails
  $wp_rewrite->add_rule("(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]",null);

  $wp_rewrite->wp_rewrite_rules();
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();

  flush_rewrite_rules();
}

add_action('admin_init','write_authorization_conditions');
```

The above only writes `RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]` but doesnt include `RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)`

I have tried

```
 $wp_rewrite->add_external_rule("RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)",null);
```

but this only adds

```
RewriteRule ^RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*) / [QSA,L]
```

How do i make this work. At the end i expect the .htaccess file to have

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*) //extra addition
  RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1] //extra addition

  //others here
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: you can customise rules with the filter [mod_rewrite_rules](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/mod_rewrite_rules/)

Comment: Do you have an example on how to achieve this with mod_rewrite_rules

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the class `WP_Rewrite`, there is currently no way to write `RewriteCond` rule as you need.

One hack to achieve what you want is to use `mod_rewrite_rules` Filter. Your RewriteRule is already written in `admin_init` action. Then in the filter, you need to check if this RewriteRule is present and then use `str_replace` to prepend `RewriteCond` line. Below is the code:

```
function write_authorization_conditions(){
  global $wp_rewrite;

  //$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("RewriteCond","%{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)",null); //this fails
  $wp_rewrite->add_rule("(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]",null);

  $wp_rewrite->wp_rewrite_rules();
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();

  flush_rewrite_rules();
}

add_action('admin_init','write_authorization_conditions');

function rewrite_auth_conditions( $rules ){

   //Check if our RewriteRule is present
   $needle = 'RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]';
   $replace = 'RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)';

   if( strpos( $rules, $needle) !== false ) { 
      $rules = str_replace($needle, $replace . "\n". $needle, $rules);      
   }
   return $rules;
}
add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'rewrite_auth_conditions');
```